# Convert Highcharts stacked daily column from "day" to "month" view

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've googled around to be able to do this but haven't found the exact solution. Basically, I have a chart with daily data, and I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically convert the chart to a "month" view? I'm trying to see if I can achieve this without making a separate request to my RESTful API to return back grouped data.

Here is a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qenE8/1/

My goal is to have a dropdown with "Day" and "Month" views. Thanks in advance for your help.

My current object for the xAxis property is this:

```
              xAxis: {

                    "type": "datetime",
                    "minTickInterval": 86400000,
                    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                        day: '%m/%d/%y' // mm/dd/yy
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use update() function on axis, and modify your tickInterval from day to month.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update()

Comment: This is useful, but I don't want to just update the axis, but rather group the counts by month.

Comment: So only data should be grouped, but ticks should be the same?